# Data Type Guessing Game

Tags: c#

I am tasked with creating a guessing game where a user can either enter in a data type, and the program must return data of the same format. Or the program will output data, and the user must type in something with the same formatting...

this is the project description:

For this project you will be creating a guessing game based on simple data types used 
in C#. Your program’s should output a number and based on the value and formatting, 
the user must enter a data type that matches the number’s (or character’s) formatting. 
The program will then prompt if a smaller data type could have been used to hold that 
value. Your program should also offer a reversed option of the game. If you type in a 
value, then it should output the correct data type.
This program should utilize byte, sbyte, int, uint, short, ushort, long, ulong, char, float, 
double, decimal and string.
Hint: Looping statements and branches will really help you to control how your 
program processes data.

---

```
    /*referenced http://www.gamedev.net/topic/462388-guess-the-number-game-c/ */
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

   namespace Guess
    {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string Value = 0;
            string UserValue = 0;
            int Switch = GenerateNumber(1,13);
            Console.WriteLine("I want to play a guessing game... do you want to guess first? (1=yes or 0=no) \r\n");
            int intTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());
            if(intTemp == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n OK... I will guess first... please type in a value: \r\n");
                UserValue = Console.Readline();
                if(
            /*randomly picks a datatype case */
            switch(Switch);
            {
            case 1:
                /*byte*/
                break;
            case 2:
                /*sbyte*/
                break;
            case 3:
                /*int*/
                break;
            case 4:
                /*uint*/
                break;
            case 5:
                /*short*/
                break;
            case 6:
                /*ushort*/
                break;
            case 7:
                /*long*/
                break;
            case 8:
                /*ulong*/
                break;
            case 9:
                /*char*/
                break;
            case 10:
                /*float*/
                break;
            case 11:
                /*double*/
                break;
            case 12:
                /*decimal*/
                break;
            case 13:
                /*string*/
                break;
            }
```

---

I am having trouble coming up with the logic to differentiate a string and char from the rest of the data types. I know that with most of them i can just do an if statement to determine if the data type is within a certain range, can someone please fill me in on some logic on how to do this?

Comment: +1 For a homework question, this is actually pretty good. Thanks for showing your attempt and exactly where you are confused!

Comment: So hidden in this wall of text is the actual question _"What is the difference between a char and a string"_? Did you try searching the web or this site for that question? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` is *exactly* one character.

A `string` is a collection of *n* number of chars (basically).

So if the input is of type string, and only one character, it *could* be a char (and probably is for your purposes). If it is any other length, it is a string.

For the other data types, a `TryParse` will fail if the input string is not a valid value for that data type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on parsing, I think I should be able to filter all of them using parse, correct?

Comment: @ColbytheEngineer Everything except `char` and `string` (obviously), yes. Remember that all the big data types will also parse the smaller ones. Small ones may well parse the big ones with an `OverflowException` so you should test it and make sure you handle that case. Also, strings that are *technically* also numbers (like 0xFF) will fail a simple `TryParse` call.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to differenciate a char represented as string and a 1 length string. (char -> string implicit conversion will hide the original type difference.)
You can (must) assume that length will choose between char and string.